# Hibernate statistics print HQL : null

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hibernate-statistics

I am new to using hibernate. I turned the statistics on, and together with normal HQL queries I get many such stats -

> `[INFO] Statistics HQL: null, time: 1724ms, rows: blah`

Can someone help me in any way with WHY a `null` query is taking around 1800ms?  Also, how can a null query be generated?