# Hibernate statistics logging "null" query

Tags: java, hibernate

So I need to benchmark the queries generated by Hibernate and their execution time for a huge spring web application.

I am using the statistics package provided by Hibernate to do it. The queries are being logged successfully but I see a strange thing in the log files.

```
2016-12-11 21:24:57,189 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 72ms, rows: 188
2016-12-11 21:24:57,208 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 18ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,209 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,211 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,213 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,214 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 0ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,216 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,218 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,219 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 0ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,221 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,222 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 0ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,224 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,225 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 0ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,227 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,228 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,229 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 0ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,231 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,232 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,233 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 0ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,235 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
2016-12-11 21:24:57,236 INFO  [org.hibernate.stat.Statistics] HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 0
```

And this goes on and on...

I need to know why hibernate is doing this. Does this indicates that something is wrong with the application?

I have already tried searching on the internet, and didn't find answers.

This has been previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357402/hibernate-log-using-hibernate-stat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888745/hibernate-statistics-print-hql-null) but these questions do not have a response on them.

I would be glad if I recieve a positive response on this...

Comment: If its already there, you could have probably asked on the same thread. This might end up being a duplicate.

Comment: @nullpointer I dont know whether that bumps the old threads or not. That is from '14 as well, so thought I will ask...

Comment: The log level for org.hibernate.stat is set to DEBUG?

Comment: @Thrasher no it's on trace currently...

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing and it looks like there is no answer yet..